# Diffuse - old school self-illuminated material

Tags: materials

I'm trying to create a material similar to the properties (old) 3ds Max "self illuminated material", in that it would ignore any lighting and the values of the diffuse texture would be what you get in the render. Just to avoid confusion I'm not after a glowing "illuminated" material.

I've made a simple Elmer cube to explain:

[image: Elmer cube]

I was hoping the colours would exactly match that of its texture map:

[image: corresponding texture map]

But if you look carefully the colours are close matches, but not exact. (Compare both the white and orange squares)

This is the material:

[image: Elmer cube material]

Comment: Hello have you tried with an Emission shader instead?

Comment: Yes, [like this?](https://artisticrender.com/blender-emission-shaders-guide/) Yes, same results as before

Comment: I can't see any difference: https://zupimages.net/up/23/21/3gmh.jpg

Comment: It was the Colour Management setting that were altering the colours!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Connect the Image Texture directly to the *Material Output* (no shader in between). IMPORTANT! - Make sure to change the *View Transform* (under *Render Properties > Color Management*) from *Filmic* to *Standard*:

[image: Lighting]

Answer (score 2):

To get rid of all the shading, you can delete the Principled BSDF in your material and instead connect a simple RGB node:

[image]

Proof: Color is Set to **R:0.5, G:0, B:0** in the Shader.
[image]

Rendered image also has **R:0.5, G:0, B:0** (right-click on any red pixel in the Image Editor)

[image]

In your case, you can simply connect your texture's Color Output directly to the Surface Pin of the Material Output Node.